# How to specify a timezone for date format in impex?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I want to specify the timezone while saving a date field. I've tried the impex above:

```
#% impex.setLocale( Locale.TURKISH );
$standardHours1=standard-hrs1

INSERT_UPDATE OpeningSchedule;code[unique=true];
                             ;$standardHours1;

INSERT WeekdayOpeningDay;openingTime[dateformat='T''HH:mm'];dayOfWeek(code,itemtype(code));closingTime[dateformat='T''HH:mm'];openingSchedule(code);&componentRef
                                ;10:00;MONDAY:WeekDay;12:30;$standardHours1;mon1
```

I've tried answers from [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12771221/how-to-define-timezone-with-date-field-while-impex.html) question from help hybris but it didn't work for me. I'm using hybris 1905.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same [source](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12771221/how-to-define-timezone-with-date-field-while-impex.html) you mentioned:

```
;startTime[dateformat='dd.MM.yyyy''T''HH:mm:ssZ']
;"23.02.2019T13:28:00+0300"
```

The `+0300` is the timezone; it's UTC+3. However, it will be converted to an equivalent value in the Hybris app server's timezone. If the Hybris app server is UTC+8, then the UTC+3 value will be converted to an equal value in UTC+8.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me. But when I don't specifiy the date part (dd.MM.yyyy) it can't parse it properly for some reason.